# Gradle Transitive Dependency Resolution

Tags: java, gradle

My project has 2 sets of JARs

1. Third party - versions cant be changed
2. Additional project JARs.

When resolving the dependencies I want the third party versions plus any transitives to take priority over the project JARs + transitives. Is there any easy way for Gradle to do this? I know I can resolve to specific versions but I want to automate the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, you can try to configure it via `ResolutionStrategy` for your build script. You can read about it in [dsl reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html). It has a [force](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method, which, according to docs:

> Allows forcing certain versions of dependencies, including transitive dependencies.

Just for example, this could be like:

```
List thirdPartyLibs = ['org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
                       'somegroup:someorg:1.0@jar']

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force thirdPartyLibs
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile thirdPartyLibs
}
```